# Rep changes on main feed should link to question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, android-app

**Exhibit A:**

[image]

Currently, clicking on rep changes in feeds does not do anything.

**It would be great for it to link to the question**, like what we already have on the web version.

---

**Exhibit B**

[image]

Rep changes which are collapsed into a single item, would have to be expanded on first click, so we can select which question to go to.

---

This functionality would be similar to what we have here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. There are several places in the app where things that should be clickable don't link anywhere only because we haven't gotten there yet. These will definitely be clickable soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in 0.1.2. The only exception is the case where there are so many reputation changes wrapped into one Feed item that you have a "and X more" line, i.e. not everything is visible. That's a fairly rare case though, but we'll add support for that eventually as well.

Comment: wow, that's a really fast update!